# How to get SMS threads

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to get a list of SMS conversations on Android. I made this Kotlin code:

```
kotlin
val threads = contentResolver.query(Telephony.Threads.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, Telephony.Threads.DATE)
```

This throws this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column null
```

I don't think am querying it the right way. What can I do to fix it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch an Inbox message try this code:

First, create a Model class of messages name **Message**

```
data class Message (
    var messageNumber:String?=null,
    var messageContent:String?=null
)
```

**Then fetch inbox message list like this:**

```
 private fun fetchInboxMsg(): ArrayList<Message>? {

        val messageList = ArrayList<Message>()
        val uriSms: Uri = Uri.parse("content://sms")

        val cursor = contentResolver.query(
            uriSms, arrayOf("DISTINCT address", "body"),  //DISTINCT
            "address IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (address",  //GROUP BY
            null, null
        )

        if (cursor!!.count > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            for (i in 0 until cursor.count) {

                val number: String? = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"))
                val content: String? = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"))
                val message = Message(number, content)

                messageList.add(message)
                cursor.moveToNext()
            }
        }

        cursor.close()
        return messageList
    }
```

Don't forget to provide permission **READ_SMS**